# Having issues to sending emails with attachment

Tags: shell, mailx

I am having issues sending emails to multiple recipients. The script is running well, creating files with the list of recipients from a table but not sending emails. I want to attach the file also. Here is a part of the script; please let me know the issue. Thank you.

if [ -s dataStnd_viol_addr.log ]; then

```
 if [ ${update_instance} == "BPROD"  ] 
  then
        ##########echo | mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Address *****" -S 
      "from=noreply@gsu.edu" -a "dataStnd_viol_addr.log" ${BPROD_LIST};
    while read dest;
        do 
            echo | mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Address *****" -S 
      "from=noreply@gsu.edu" $dest < $REPORT/dataStnd_viol_addr.log
        done < $REPORT/Email_PRODlist.lst
    elif [ ${update_instance} == "B8QA"  ]
    then
        while read dest1;
        do 
            echo | mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Address *****" -S 
    "from=noreply@gsu.edu" $dest1 < $REPORT/dataStnd_viol_addr.log
        done < $REPORT/Email_QAlist.lst
        
else 
    while read dest2;
        do 
            echo | mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Address *****" -S 
  "from=noreply@gsu.edu" $dest2 < $REPORT/dataStnd_viol_addr.log
            
        done < $REPORT/Email_DEVlist.lst 
fi
```

fi

```
cd ${working_dir}

working_dir=""; export working_dir
working_sql_dir=""; export working_sql_dir
update_instance=""; export update_instance
days_back=""; export days_back
```

Answer (score 0):

You're providing input to mailx **both** with a pipe and with redirection. I don't know which takes precedence. I'd recommend removing all the `echo|` bits

Also, there seem to be 2 competing redirections, and mailx might be slurping up the input to the while loop.

Try this:

```bash
subject="***** Data Standard Violation - Address *****"
logfile="$REPORT/dataStnd_viol_addr.log"

while IFS= read -r dest2 <&3 ;do 
    mailx -s "$subject" -S "from=noreply@gsu.edu" "$dest2" < "$logfile"
done 3< "$REPORT/Email_DEVlist.lst"
```

`read` is using file descriptor 3 and `mailx` is using file descriptor 1, no potential for conflict.

Note that this won't *attach* the file: the file contents will be the message body. Check if your version of mailx has a `-a` option.

Comment: I am using the following to send emails to multiple recipients, reading from the file, but it only sends to the first email address in the file. Please let me know what I am doing right?

Comment: while IFS= read -r email_dev;
  do 
   mailx -s "$subject2" -S "from=noreply@gsu.edu" -S "from=noreply@gsu.edu"  -a $reports_dir/data_stnd_viol_allcaps.log "$email_dev"
  done < "$reports_dir/Email_DEVlist.lst"
  #while read email_dev;
  #do
  # mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Allcaps *****" -S "from=noreply@gsu.edu" -a $reports_dir/data_stnd_viol_allcaps.log  "$email_dev"
  #done < $reports_dir/Email_DEVlist.lst

Comment: You have both `read` and `mailx` reading stdin. The _body_ of the email to the first dev will contain the list of the remaining devs. Use `read -r email_dev <&3` and `done 3< file`, and also provide some input to mailx so you have a message body.